# Matlab - vision.VideoFileReader never reads audio samples

Tags: matlab, audio, video, h.264, mpeg-4

I tried to read a video (and it's audio) using `vision.VideoFileReader` like this:

```
video = vision.VideoFileReader('test.mp4', 'AudioOutputPort', true);

while ~isDone( video )
     [frame, audioSample] = step(video);
end
```

However, `audioSample` is always a logic 0.

**EDIT:** The video has audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the code, or the specific file, but the file type.

From [the help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-class.html#):

> Reading audio from compressed MP4 files with video and audio is not supported by vision.VideoFileReader.

The most obvious solution would be to convert (outside Matlab using the method of your choice) to a format that `vision.VideoFileReader` can handle, such as .avi